# Grep Search And Replace in Mass Files

Tags: grep

Even though there are lots of grep questions and answers, these don't answer and I need help in this. I need to make

```
Title-BEX-override-8>"
```

expressions to become

```
Title-BEX>"
```

Any letters or words among `Title-BEX` and `>"` should be terminated. I need an exact grep expression for this.

And some optional answers can be about this: I want to do is thin multiple files. And prefer doing this in Mac.

Answer (score 0):

grep cannot do text replacement.

try `sed`

```
sed 's/Title-BEX-override-8/Title-BEX/g' file
```

-i option can let you do it "in place". but I don't know the corresponding option is for your sed on mac.. :(

Comment: Thank you Kent. I just updated the question please have a look. Change about >"